# PHP Best Practice: Using Mixed return types

Tags: php, coding-style

I understand that this topic was briefly approached [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525507/php-returning-mixed-data-types-good-or-bad) but I hope to understand the general do's and don'ts of using multiple return types in PHP.
There seems to be varied opinions about this feature of PHP.

I would tend to agree that, as pointed out in the thread linked above, for errors, using exceptions is probably more suited; But, what about a function returning, say, two types of meaningful values? For example, let's say a function that returns all the lights that are OFF in a house (:) yes, I'm winging it!)

Essentially, this is what I want to convey: If a basic condition is not met and I don't see a point in going forward and computing my list, I return a boolean. Otherwise, go ahead and do so:

```
    public function getLightsThatAreOff($house) 
    {
        // if $house itself does not have any power, return true 
        // else 
              //compile an array of lights that are off and return then
    }
```

I would think that the use case mentioned above is a sort of a sweet-spot for multiple return types. In either case, I would appreciate it if someone provides a general set of guidelines on how to determine whether to use this feature or not.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd personally say that getLightsThatAreOff() has meaning only when the power is on. When called when the power is off it has meaningless results, I'd say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mixed types are not good, even if documented well. For example, if a method is returning an array, but there is nothing to return, then it should be an empty array, not false or anything else.
i.e.

```
array()
```

Comment: I guess being conservative is probably a good approach: avoid mixed types wherever possible?

Comment: Yep, avoid mixed - most of the time it is possible

Comment: Also PHP7 strict type will not allow mixed type or null.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you intend to use these functions. Even if you're part of a large development team, as long as you document your code effectively, then you should be able to safely return mixed types. If you develop for yourself, then it really doesn't matter, as long as you know how and where to use your functions.

I will say though, from personal experience, that whenever you can alleviate the possibility of an error, you should. Meaning, if the expected return value of a function is an array, you should probably return a blank array instead of a boolean (false). That way, even if someone doesn't read your documentation, the worst that can happen is that when they try to loop through the array, nothing happens, and the script continues. If you can't foresee it causing any issues, I would highly recommend doing it this way instead of simply returning false. I can't even count how many times I've heard "your database class is broken" when I returned false instead of an array of results if the query failed.

Comment: Whether you're part of a team of not is irrelevant, you should always write the function in the way that makes the most sense and has the least drawbacks. A drawback of mixed return types can be an overhead in dealing with the return values on the caller's side.

Comment: Agree with @deceze. Nevertheless PHP itself does return mixed types frequently. Even in last versions (7+). `password_hash()` is an example.

Comment: Returning empty array may be correct in some scenarios, but it depends. If array with data is needed/expected then anything else could be construed as a problem/error. So throw an exception or return null. People might do `is_array` and then start looping. OR have to check if is iterable and if has values. It's all much more work than just `=== null` or wrap in a simple try/catch, imo